# How to use IntentService thread using RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2, intentservice

I faced with the next situation. I start my code in onHadleIntent method and some part of the code is worked in IntentService thread but the Observable.zip method in getInfoAboutUser() is worked in RxJava thread.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
      LOG.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName());

      Call<String> call= mRepository.getInfo();
        try {
            retrofit2.Response<String> response = call.execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                LOG.debug("Response body "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                getInfoAboutUser();
            }
       }catch(){}
}

public void getInfoAboutUser(){
       LOG.debug("getInfoAboutUser "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

       Executor e = new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
                LOG.debug(" executor thread");
                runnable.run();
            }
        }; 

 Observable.zip(
                Observable.fromIterable(array),
                Observable
                        .interval((mRandom.nextInt(7)+5) * 1000, 
 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,Schedulers.from(e))
                        .take(array.size()),
                new BiFunction<String, Long, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(String s, Long aLong) throws Exception {
                        LOG.debug("Result "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        return s;
                    }
                }
       ).flatMapMaybe(new Function<String, MaybeSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public MaybeSource<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                return mRepository.getInfoAboutUser(s); 
            }
        }).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {})
}
```

mRepository.getInfo() and mRepository.getInfoAboutUser(s) methods I am using without subscribeOn and observeOn!

My log is:

- IntentService thread
- IntentService thread Response body
- IntentService thread getInfoAboutUser
- RxSingleScheduler-1 executor thread
- RxSingleScheduler-1 Result

etc

What shall i do to use IntentService thread for Observable.zip and Interval methods? I need only IntentService thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Schedulers.from(e)` wraps the `Executor` in the internal class `ExecutorScheduler`. If a task is scheduled with a delay and the given `Executor` is not a `ScheduledExecutorService` then it will use an internal scheduler to delay the call to `e.execute()` until the delay is finished.

Because your executor simply immediately executes, it ends up executing on the helper scheduler which is `RxSingleScheduler-1`.

To solve this you need to choose from the following solutions:

1. Create a `ScheduledExecutorService` which correctly dispatches the runnables to the `IntentService`.
2. Create a custom `Scheduler` which dispatches the runnables to the `IntentService`'s `Looper`.
3. Use the [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) library to do 2. for you. `AndroidSchedulers.from(Looper.myLooper())` will create a scheduler for the `IntentService`.

Edit: Please do note that `IntentService` and asynchronous operations don't mix. The service will terminate when `handleIntent` returns so it is not the a good 
way to execute delayed operations like `Observable.interval`.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Can your explain how would you solve this problem if long operations are needed? And how to implement 1 task? I can get an intentService looper using looper =Looper.myLooper() then i can get looper thread looper.getThread() or using Thread.currentThread() but how to bind this thread to  ScheduledExecutorService?

Comment: I added to interval method  an AndroidSchedulers.from(Looper.myLooper() but this item doesn't work. The interval method doesn't work and doesn't produce errors

Comment: Like I said the IntentService shuts down after the `handleIntent` method returns, this includes the Looper it manages. This means the scheduled interval is cancelled.